# AmCharts - Position ChartScrollbar on Bottom?

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, amcharts

Is this possible? Legends have this attribute (top/bottom), and `amStockCharts` library has this configuration option as well. So, for the "regular" `amCharts` library, is it possible to position the chartScrollbar on the bottom?

I want to avoid any CSS hacks after the chart draws as well.

Comment: from the [docs](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/ChartScrollbarSettings) the Chart Scrollbar has its default position to be on the bottom.. whats the issue?

Comment: I know it's on the StockCharts docs, but seems to be missing for regular charting library. It's a different product / license. Curious if anyone has a workaround for the basic amChart library.

Comment: oh gotcha.. well if you really need to change that you could probably just inspect the chart in your browser.. find the scrollbar and do something like `position: absolute; bottom: 0` but I wouldn't know without testing

Comment: Trying to do so without any CSS after graphs draw. Updated q - thanks anyway.

Comment: sure thing... there is no documentation so you may not be able to without css hacks :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the latest update to AmCharts, this has been added as a config option. You can set "oppositeAxis: false" on chartScrollbar properties to move the scrollbar to the bottom. Hope this can be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Position of a Scrollbar in our regular JavaScript charts is always opposite the axis. So you have to set categoryAxis.position = "top" in order scrollbar to be at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks. Figured it out in that way, but that's swapping the axis. I actually contacted them and there's no way to draw the scrollbar beneath the category axis when it's on the bottom, but it may make it into a future release.

Comment: It's strange that this is the only way.
[stock amcharts3](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/ChartScrollbarSettings) has this option as I think is the better way: adding a position: "bottom" to the scrollsettings

Answer (score 0):

I'm late but I didn't find a better solution elsewhere. You can use

```
chartScrollbar.oppositeAxis = false;
chartScrollbar.offset = 20;
```

This will push the scrollbar next to the categoryAxis. Use the offset to move the scrollbar away from the labels.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by changing `chart.scrollbarX.parent` value like this:

```
chart.scrollbarX.parent = chart.bottomAxesContainer;
```